# XSLT transform fails in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

I have run into a weird problem. I have a XSLT file that is applied on a source XML to produce a target XML.
Here's the code that I am using

```
      XslCompiledTransform myXslTransform;
      myXslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
      string xsltPath = @"..\Support\CustomerXMlTransform.xslt";
      myXslTransform.Load(xsltPath);
      string tempPath = "C:\Transformed.XML";
      myXslTransform.Transform(xmlFilePath, tempPath);
```

This works perfectly  fine when run through Visual Studio (running VS 2010).
When I try to run the app from an installer(created from VS) and passed an XML, the transformed XML just has one tag and all the values from the source tags are spitted out like so ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectManagement>

    004 Some
    Project Description
    7230652
    898808
    676
    2003
    003
    Customer Article Description

</ProjectManagement>
```

There are more values but I have deleted them here. No tags are shown for the values reported, it's like a partial output.

Anyone knows what's going on here?
Regards.

Have checked the installation folder and found that the System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq.dll files were missing. These are the files referred in the project. Copied those two files manually to the installation folder. Still the same result without nodes!!!

Here's the XSLT which works fine from VS 2010 but fails with the installer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ProjectManagement>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ProjectManagement>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="kalkulation">
    <Project>
      <ProjectCategoryName>WellTeam</ProjectCategoryName>
      <ProjectNumber>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">ProjectNumber</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="projektnummer"/>
      </ProjectNumber>
      <ProjectName>
        <xsl:if test="string-length(projektnummer)!=0">
          <xsl:if test ="string-length(kunden_kurzbezeichnung)!=0">
            <xsl:if test ="string-length(kunden_artikel_bezeichnung)!=0">
              <xsl:value-of select="concat(projektnummer,'',kunden_kurzbezeichnung,'',kunden_artikel_bezeichnung)"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
      </ProjectName>
      <TemplateName>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="u_firma=003 and material_gruppe = 0321">Group1</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="u_firma=004 and material_gruppe = 0321">Group2</xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>Group1</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </TemplateName>
      <CalculationNumber>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">CalculationNumber</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="kalkulationsnummer"/>
      </CalculationNumber>
      <CalculationSubNumber>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">CalculationSubNumber</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="kalkulations_u_nummer"/>
      </CalculationSubNumber>
      <Mandator>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">Mandant</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue">676</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(mandant,0,3)"/>
      </Mandator>
      <CompanyName>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">CompanyName</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">IO</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue">100</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(firma,0,4)"/>
      </CompanyName>
      <CompanySubName>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">CompanySubName</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">IO</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(u_firma,0,4)"/>
      </CompanySubName>
      <ArticleIndication>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">ArticleIndication</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">IO</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(bezeichnung,0,40)"/>
      </ArticleIndication>
      <PartNumber>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">PartNumber</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue">0</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="teilenummer"/>
      </PartNumber>
      <DueDate>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="faelligkeitsdatum"/>
      </DueDate>
      <InsideSalesPerson1>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">InsideSalesPerson1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(sachbearbeiter1,0,20)"/>
      </InsideSalesPerson1>
      <InsideSalesPerson2>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">InsideSalesPerson2</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(sachbearbeiter2,0,20)"/>
      </InsideSalesPerson2>
      <SalesPerson>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">SalesPerson</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(vertreter_kunde,0,60)"/>
      </SalesPerson>
      <Status>
        <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
        <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
        <xsl:variable name="status" select="translate(status, $smallcase,$uppercase)" />
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$status='NEW' or $status= 'NEU'">1</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$status='READY' or $status='FERTIG'">2</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$status='IN BEARBEITUNG'">3</xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>        
      </Status>
      <StatusText>
        <xsl:value-of select="status"/>
      </StatusText>
      <CustomerNo>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(kunden_nummer,0,7)"/>
      </CustomerNo>
      <CustomerSubNo>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">CustomerSubNumber</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">IO</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="kunden_u_nr"/>
      </CustomerSubNo>
      <CustomerShortDesc>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">CustomerDescription</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">IO</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(kunden_kurzbezeichnung,0,20)"/>
      </CustomerShortDesc>
      <CustomerArticleDescription>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">CustomerArticleDescription</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">IO</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(kunden_artikel_bezeichnung,0,255)"/>
      </CustomerArticleDescription>
      <CustomerArticleNumber>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">CustomerArticleNumber</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(kunden_artikel_nummer,0,30)"/>
      </CustomerArticleNumber>
      <TaskType>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">TaskType</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(aufgabe_art,0,3)"/>
      </TaskType>
      <TaskCreator>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">TaskCreator</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(aufgabe_ersteller,0,20)"/>
      </TaskCreator>
      <TaskDate>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">TaskDate</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="aufgabe_erstellt_am"/>
      </TaskDate>
      <TaskInfo>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">TaskInformation</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(aufgabe_information,0,255)"/>
      </TaskInfo>
      <DesignerId>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">TaskSpecialist</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(aufgabe_sachbearbeiter,0,3)"/>
      </DesignerId>
      <MixFactor>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">MixedFactor</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(mengen_faktor,'0.00')"/>
      </MixFactor>
      <DivideNumber>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">DivideNumber</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(teilenummer,0,3)"/>
      </DivideNumber>
      <ProjectDesc>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">ProjectDescription</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="Projektbezeichnung"/>
      </ProjectDesc>
      <MaterialGroup>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">MaterialGroup</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">I</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(material_gruppe,0,3)"/>
      </MaterialGroup>
      <MaterialDescription>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">IO</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="material_bezeichnung"/>
      </MaterialDescription>
      <Inactively>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">IO</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue">0</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="inaktiv"/>
      </Inactively>
      <ShipManually>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">ShipManually</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">IO</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="verlade_manuell"/>
      </ShipManually>
      <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
    </Project>
    <Documents>
      <CadDocs>
        <DesignParams>
          <Design>
            <DesignName>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring(cad_nummer,0,9)"/>
            </DesignName>
            <DesignCategoryName>DEFAULT DESIGN CATEGORY</DesignCategoryName>
            <StandardName>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring(fefco_nr,0,15)"/>
            </StandardName>
            <Board Code="">
              <Sort>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(sorte_nummer,0,15)"/>
              </Sort>
              <Quality>
                <xsl:value-of select="boardquality"/>
              </Quality>
              <Grammage>
                <xsl:value-of select="boardgrammage"/>
              </Grammage>
            </Board>
            <FluteDirection>
              <xsl:value-of select="designflutedirection"/>
            </FluteDirection>
            <GrainDirection>
              <xsl:value-of select="designgraindirection"/>
            </GrainDirection>
            <MatType>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring(material_typ,0,3)"/>
            </MatType>
            <Length>
              <xsl:value-of select="laenge"/>
            </Length>
            <Width>
              <xsl:value-of select="breite"/>
            </Width>
            <Depth>
              <xsl:value-of select="hoehe"/>
            </Depth>
          </Design>
        </DesignParams>
        <xsl:text>
            </xsl:text>
      </CadDocs>
    </Documents>
    <DesignOutput>
      <StandardUsed>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(fefco_nr,0,15)"/>
      </StandardUsed>
      <BlankArea>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
      </BlankArea>
      <AreaRatio>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
      </AreaRatio>
      <BlankLength>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">BlankLength</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="laengen_zuschnitt"/>
      </BlankLength>
      <BlankWidth>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">BlankWidth</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="breiten_zuschnitt"/>
      </BlankWidth>
      <ManualCutLength>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">ManualCutLength</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="breiten_laengen_zuschnitt_manuell"/>
      </ManualCutLength>
      <FoldedBoxLength>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">LengthOfFoldedBox</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="verlade_laenge"/>
      </FoldedBoxLength>
      <FoldedBoxWidth>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">WidthOfFoldedBox</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="verlade_breite"/>
      </FoldedBoxWidth>
      <FoldedBoxHeight>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">HeightOfFoldedBox</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="verlade_hoehe"/>
      </FoldedBoxHeight>
      <CreaseLength1>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">CreaseLength1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="bz_riller"/>
      </CreaseLength1>
      <CreaseWidth1>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">CreaseWidth1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="lz_riller"/>
      </CreaseWidth1>
      <CreaseLength2>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">CreaseLength2</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="bz_schlitzer"/>
      </CreaseLength2>
      <CreaseWidth2>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributename">CreaseWidth2</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="lz_schlitzer"/>
      </CreaseWidth2>
      <ARDFile>
        <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
      </ARDFile>
      <PDFFile>
        <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
      </PDFFile>
    </DesignOutput>
    <LayoutParams>
      <LayoutCategoryID>DEFAULT MANUFACTURING CATEGORY</LayoutCategoryID>
      <MfgFile Name="">
        <TrimTop>
          <xsl:value-of select="trimtop"/>
        </TrimTop>
        <TrimRight>
          <xsl:value-of select="trimright"/>
        </TrimRight>
        <TrimLeft>
          <xsl:value-of select="trimleft"/>
        </TrimLeft>
        <TrimBottom>
          <xsl:value-of select="trimbottom"/>
        </TrimBottom>
        <SheetSizeX>
          <xsl:value-of select="breiten_zuschnitt_vernutzt"/>
        </SheetSizeX>
        <SheetSizeY>
          <xsl:value-of select="laengen_zuschnitt_vernutzt"/>
        </SheetSizeY>
        <GutterX>
          <xsl:value-of select="gutterx"/>
        </GutterX>
        <GutterY>
          <xsl:value-of select="guttery"/>
        </GutterY>
        <GrainDir>
          <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="layoutgraindirection"/>
        </GrainDir>
        <WastePercentage>
          <xsl:value-of select="abfall_netto_bogen"/>
        </WastePercentage>
      </MfgFile>
    </LayoutParams>
    <LayoutOutput>
      <TrimTop>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributeid"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="trimtop"/>
      </TrimTop>
      <TrimRight>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributeid"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="trimright"/>
      </TrimRight>
      <TrimLeft>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributeid"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="trimleft"/>
      </TrimLeft>
      <TrimBottom>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributeid"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="trimbottom"/>
      </TrimBottom>
      <SheetSizeX>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributeid"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="breiten_zuschnitt_vernutzt"/>
      </SheetSizeX>
      <SheetSizeY>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributeid"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="laengen_zuschnitt_vernutzt"/>
      </SheetSizeY>
      <EdgePunchingLength>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributeid"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="laengen_zuschnitt_stanzrand"/>
      </EdgePunchingLength>
      <EdgePunchingWidth>
        <xsl:attribute name="attributeid"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">O</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="defaultvalue"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="breiten_zuschnitt_stanzrand"/>
      </EdgePunchingWidth>
      <NumUps>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="vernutzung"/>
      </NumUps>
      <CutSizeX>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="nutzen_breite"/>
      </CutSizeX>
      <CutSizeY>
        <xsl:attribute name="expressionname"></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="nutzen_laenge"/>
      </CutSizeY>
      <MFGFile>
        <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
      </MFGFile>
      <PDFFile>
        <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
      </PDFFile>
      <CF2File>
        <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
      </CF2File>
    </LayoutOutput>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here's the XML tested with VS 2010 (which works fine) and the installer:

```
<box_xml>
  <bsi_cad2box>
    <projektnummer>004</projektnummer>
    <Projektbezeichnung>Project Description</Projektbezeichnung>
    <kalkulationsnummer>7230652</kalkulationsnummer>
    <kalkulations_u_nummer>898808</kalkulations_u_nummer>
    <mandant>676</mandant>
    <firma>2003</firma>
    <u_firma>003</u_firma>
    <bezeichnung>Customer Article Description</bezeichnung>
    <teilenummer>1</teilenummer>
    <faelligkeitsdatum>2012-01-12T00:00:00</faelligkeitsdatum>
    <sachbearbeiter1>3009</sachbearbeiter1>
    <sachbearbeiter2>30</sachbearbeiter2>
    <vertreter_kunde>201</vertreter_kunde>
    <status>neu</status>
    <kunden_nummer>716523</kunden_nummer>
    <kunden_u_nr>1001</kunden_u_nr>
    <kunden_kal_key>132132</kunden_kal_key>
    <kunden_kurzbezeichnung>Maier</kunden_kurzbezeichnung>
    <kunden_artikel_bezeichnung>Customer Article Description</kunden_artikel_bezeichnung>
    <kunden_artikel_nummer>TestKdNr 12345</kunden_artikel_nummer>
    <aufgabe_art>100</aufgabe_art>
    <aufgabe_erstellt_am>2012-01-12T00:00:00</aufgabe_erstellt_am>
    <aufgabe_ersteller>100</aufgabe_ersteller>
    <aufgabe_information>Aufgabeninfo</aufgabe_information>
    <aufgabe_sachbearbeiter>100</aufgabe_sachbearbeiter>
    <cad_nummer>00725</cad_nummer>
    <fefco_nr>2201</fefco_nr>
    <mengen_faktor>0.00</mengen_faktor>
    <vernutzung>0</vernutzung>
    <breite>205.00</breite>
    <laenge>360.00</laenge>
    <hoehe>75.00</hoehe>
    <breiten_zuschnitt>3602</breiten_zuschnitt>
    <laengen_zuschnitt>2052</laengen_zuschnitt>
    <breiten_laengen_zuschnitt_manuell>0</breiten_laengen_zuschnitt_manuell>
    <nutzen_breite>0.00</nutzen_breite>
    <nutzen_laenge>0.00</nutzen_laenge>
    <breiten_zuschnitt_vernutzt>4</breiten_zuschnitt_vernutzt>
    <laengen_zuschnitt_vernutzt>1100</laengen_zuschnitt_vernutzt>
    <breiten_zuschnitt_stanzrand>0</breiten_zuschnitt_stanzrand>
    <laengen_zuschnitt_stanzrand>4</laengen_zuschnitt_stanzrand>
    <sorte_nummer>M-SBS-300</sorte_nummer>
    <inaktiv>0</inaktiv>
    <material_typ></material_typ>
    <material_nummer></material_nummer>
    <material_gruppe>0321</material_gruppe>
    <material_bezeichnung></material_bezeichnung>
    <verlade_breite>0.00</verlade_breite>
    <verlade_laenge>0.00</verlade_laenge>
    <verlade_hoehe>0.00</verlade_hoehe>
    <verlade_manuell>0</verlade_manuell>
    <bz_riller></bz_riller>
    <lz_riller></lz_riller>
    <bz_schlitzer></bz_schlitzer>
    <lz_schlitzer></lz_schlitzer>
    <abfall_netto_bogen>19.50</abfall_netto_bogen>
    <kaschierbogen_sorte_nummer>
    </kaschierbogen_sorte_nummer>
    <kaschierbogen_breiten_zuschnitt>0.00</kaschierbogen_breiten_zuschnitt>
    <kaschierbogen_laengen_zuschnitt>0.00</kaschierbogen_laengen_zuschnitt>
    <kaschierbogen_breite_zuschnitt_rand>0.00</kaschierbogen_breite_zuschnitt_rand>
    <kaschierbogen_laengen_zuschnitt_rand>0.00</kaschierbogen_laengen_zuschnitt_rand>
    <legevariante_nummer>
    </legevariante_nummer>
    <druck_ff_nummer>
    </druck_ff_nummer>
    <druck_ff_art>
    </druck_ff_art>
    <druck_ff_womit>
    </druck_ff_womit>
    <ver_ff_nummer>
    </ver_ff_nummer>
    <ver_ff_art>
    </ver_ff_art>
    <ver_ff_womit>
    </ver_ff_womit>
    <stanzen_ff_nummer>
    </stanzen_ff_nummer>
    <stanzen_ff_art>
    </stanzen_ff_art>
    <stanzen_ff_womit>
    </stanzen_ff_womit>
    <kasch_ff_nummer>
    </kasch_ff_nummer>
    <kasch_ff_art>
    </kasch_ff_art>
    <kasch_ff_womit>
    </kasch_ff_womit>
    <bsi_cad2box_ff>
      <typ>gsm</typ>
      <text>14.16</text>
      <n_wert>14.16</n_wert>
    </bsi_cad2box_ff>
    <bsi_cad2box_ff>
      <typ>dru</typ>
      <text>
      </text>
      <n_wert>0.00</n_wert>
    </bsi_cad2box_ff>
    <bsi_cad2box_ff>
      <typ>kas</typ>
      <text>
      </text>
      <n_wert>0.00</n_wert>
    </bsi_cad2box_ff>
    <DOKUMENT>
      <typ>
      </typ>
      <name>
      </name>
      <version>
      </version>
      <erstellungs_datum>
      </erstellungs_datum>
      <url>
      </url>
    </DOKUMENT>
  </bsi_cad2box>
</box_xml>
```

Found the bug, yeah!!!
First of all thanks to Marc for pointing in the right direction. The problem was in the XSLT. The tag which should have the value as 'bsi_cad2box' actually has 'kalkulation'.
So there you go, I was under a time crunch so could not think out of the box.
Thanks again for everyone.

Regards.

Comment: Could you provide input XML and XSL files?

Comment: My assumption is your xslt is at fault, and/or the xml supplied is subtly different to the xml you tested against. Would need to see samples of both.

Comment: does the result differ from vs2010 and your installation on the same maschine?

Comment: I think that the current directory in the two cases is different and because your XSLT file-path is specified as a relative URI, in the second case the XSLT file isn't found. Typically, the current directory is where the main executable resides, but for Windows Services it is `C:\Windows\System32`

Answer (score 0):

**I think that the current directory in the two cases is different**. Because your XSLT file-path is specified as a relative URI, in the second case the XSLT file isn't found.

Typically, the current directory is where the main executable resides, but for Windows Services it is `C:\Windows\System32`.

**One way to determine the current application's path**:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
```